# How to print 2 echo in li

Tags: php, html, pagination

how to print 2 `echo` in 1 `li`

i have code like this

```
    <li class='page-item'>
        <?php 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++)
      {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages))
          {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $page)
            {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo "<li class='page-item'>
          $x</li>";
      // if not current page...
          }
else
          {
         // make it a link
         echo "<li class='page-item'>
         <a href='paging.php?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
           } // end else
        } // end if
      } // end for

    ?>
    </li>
```

my paging, active state out of `li` block
[image]

Comment: This question is incredibly confusing. What are you trying to echo out?

Comment: i want to print out `echo [<b>$x</b>]";` and `echo "<a href='paging.php?page=$x'>$x</a>";` in one block `li`

i mean im want to print that `[1]` in `<<[2][3]>>`

Comment: Take a look at the html source code.  Edit your post with what you find.

Comment: im already trying to add page item but still active state out of pagination block

Comment: I'm trying to help you see what's wrong and learn how to troubleshoot by yourself.  View the html source, copy the code in question and edit the question so we can see.  I already know what the problem is; I want you to see it first.

Comment: smh... by changing it to have nested list items, you've undoubtedly broken the css.  Where is the code you are trying to imitate?  It would make it a lot easier to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `a href` to `x`

```
<li class='page-item'>
    <?php 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++)
      {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages))
          {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $page)
            {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo "
          <a href='#'>$x</a>";
      // if not current page...
          }
else
          {
         // make it a link
         echo "
         <a href='paging.php?page=$x'>$x</a>";
           } // end else
        } // end if
      } // end for

    ?>
    </li>
```

Comment: That may have fixed your styling, but now you have the problem that it's an active link, when your intention is to have it not clickable.  To truly fix this you need to look at the css.  Judging from the styling already present, someone has already thought it out, and the answer is in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<li class='page-item'>
<?php 
  for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++){
     if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages)) {
        if ($x == $page) { ?>         
           [<b> <?php echo $x; ?> </b>]
        <?php }
     }else{ ?>
       <a href='paging.php?page= <?php echo $x;?> >  <?php echo $x; ?> </a>
     <?php }         
  }
?>
</li>
```

in this line:

```
[<b> <?php echo $x; ?> </b>]
```

are you sure you want to print out []?

Comment: im just want to print x, no problem without []

Comment: active state not displaying, when im click 2, 2 not displaying

Comment: page number start with -1, and unlimited page number

Comment: create a snippet

Comment: how to create a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the order PHP is printing stuff out. The problem is with your HTML.

```
php > $page=1;
php > $range=3;
php > $total_pages = 50;
php > for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++)
php >       {
php {    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages))
php {           {
php {       if ($x == $page)
php {             {
php {          echo "
php "           [<b>$x</b>]";
php {           }
php { else
php {           {
php {          echo "<a href='paging.php?page=$x'>$x</a>";
php {            } 
php {         }
php {       }

          [<b>1</b>]<a href='paging.php?page=2'>2</a><a href='paging.php?page=3'>3</a><a href='paging.php?page=4'>4</a>
php >
```

First, you will need to encapsulate the brackets if you want to apply a style to them.

And if the brackets are causing the echo to interpret things funny, use single quotes like so:
`'[<b>' . $x . '</b>]` or use htmlentities.